# Изменить содержимое Label в главном окне из страницы WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Всем доброго времени суток. Я начинаю разбирать MVVM и появился вопрос. Как отловить изменения для содержимого элемента управления. В главном окне реализовано страничная навигация. Красным подмечено где подгружаются и изменяются страницы. Мне нужно изменять "шапку" в окне, на рисунке желтым отмечено, в зависимости от того что нажал пользователь на странице. К примеру "Полевой дневник", то когда страница поменяется в "шапке" должно замениться содержимое. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через привязку? При нажатии карточки у вас меняется VM? Привяжите шапку к свойству в этом VM, например

Comment: @АндрейNOP пробовал через привязку, не получилось. При нажатии на карточку, у меня меняется VM на другую

Comment: у меня тоже была такая проблема, я делал через события (`event`), не уверен что так правильно, но всё нормально работало

Comment: https://github.com/PekorP/ChessTrainer/blob/master/ChessTrainer/ViewModels/MainWindowViewModel.cs , https://github.com/PekorP/ChessTrainer/blob/master/ChessTrainer/ViewModels/ChessTrainerViewModel.cs . В первой ссылке чекни `ChessTrainerViewModelOnChangeTrainer` на 96 строке, во второй ссылке чекни строки 53 и 70-79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если при нажатии на какую-то страницу у вас фиксируется это изменение где-то, то можно через простой if-else проверять какая страница нажата и изменять текст. Если при смене страницы - нет доступа к свойству текста шапки, то попробуйте создать эвент который бы вызывался при смене страницы и условно в EventArgs кидать имя страницы. Без вашего кода очень сложно понять организованную структуру и помочь сложнее, я бы сделал через эвент либо кастомный класс Навигации.

Comment: согласен насчет `event'а` (почему-то только после написания комментария под вопросом прочитал ответ :) ), только вот лучше сделать не if-else, как мне кажется, а dictionary

Comment: @Pekor, да, я делал абсолютно также. Можно в CommandParameter у Button биндить название из Dictionary и потом подставлять в Frame для загрузки страницы по Uri (но увы, так нельзя использовать перегрузки запуска страницы). Как ещё 1 существенный плюс, можно биндить название открытой страницы в Title всего окна